# Almacenar el valor de una consulta SQL access en una variable VBA excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Estoy trabajando en un libro de excel sobre un modulo de vba, realizo una conexión a base de datos access y genero una consulta

```
obSQL = "SELECT Nombre_unidad FROM TBL_UNIDADES;"
```

Esta consulta siempre siempre me traerá como resultado un solo dato, y quiero poder poner ese resultado en una variable la cual usare inmediatamente para realizar otra consulta en otra base de datos access.

Comment: Suerte en tu proyecto! Si tienes alguna duda estamos aquí para ayudar!

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes? Haz la petición usando un objecto Recordset, y luego guarda el dato en una variable. Algo en plan `mivariable = rst.Fields(0).value` debería funcionar

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, voy a intentarlo y te cuento como  me fue.

Comment: Elier Sanchez, gracias lo use a la perfección

Comment: @Elier, debieras realizar tu publicación como respuesta, para que el AP pueda aceptarla.

Answer (score -1):

Estaría muy bueno que pongas la parte de tu código donde traes los datos del Access para ser mas concisos a la hora de ayudarte pero según lo que decís con esto me imagino que te va a ayudar para hacer exactamente lo que necesitas.

```
static public string path = "Aca tu connection string";
static public OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(path);
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Creamos un datatable llamado dt
using (conn) //Usamos el OleDbConnection
 {
     if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) //Con esto nos aseguramos que la ruta este cerrada antes de abrirla por los errores comunes que puede arraigar 
       {
         conn.ConnectionString = path;
         conn.Open();
       }

     string query = "SELECT Columnas FROM Tabla"; //Aca tu query
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn); //Enviamos los datos al servidor
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd); //Adaptamos la respuesta que tuvimos mediante un OleDbDataAdapter
     da.Fill(dt); //Los datos adaptados ahora lo organizamos en la datatable que creamos al inicio. 
 }

string valor = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(); //Traes el valor de la primera celda de la primer fila del DataTable.
```